# Do I effectively lose two opportunities to have an encounter when I get arrested by patrols?

Tags: arkham-horror, arkham-horror-curse-of-dark-pharaoh

When I get arrested by patrols during the movement phase, I get moved to the jail and am told to become delayed and skip the entire next turn. Does this mean I miss this turn's encounter phase **and** next turn's as well, merely standing up during the movement phase of that next turn and sitting idle in the polic station? This would mean effectively sitting out of two potential encounters (granted you could say not quite two, as the first turn would sometimes simply be spent in the streets, not necessarily a location).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Delayed** means two things

1. The investigator cannot move during his turn
2. The investigator does not receive movement points during his turn

Everything else is still on. You'd get your normal encounter for the area you are in, you can trade items, etc.

Arrested is worse.
Yes, you would miss your entire next turn, including the encounter.  Thereby effectively losing two encounters.

Comment: Being arrested seems to be more than just being delayed. The text on pg 16 under "Arrested Investigators" says "The player completely skips the next turn, simply standing his investigator marker and placing it in the main area of the Police Station during the Movement Phase. The player may act in the following turn as normal."

Comment: @joey - my bad, reading too fast.  Yes, arrested would result in you missing two encounters